# Transit through USA with Canadian Temporary Passport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, passports, canadian-citizens

I am traveling from Malaysia to Toronto with a stopover in Tokyo and USA. Is my temporary Canadian passport enough to transit through the airport?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know a Canadian temporary passport is valid in all places a full Canadian passport is valid. The only difference is its limited duration and the requirement to exchange it for a full passport at a pre-arranged time and place. Neither USA nor Japan require visas for transiting Canadians.

However this is something you should have asked the consulate when they issued you the temporary passport. They would have asked you about the route you were taking home, and if there was a doubt you should have checked that the passport would be adequate.

Comment: Sometimes there are some relatively strange decisions on recognition of alternative travel documents. For example, Sweden and Iceland apparently does not explicitly recognize the temporary passports issued by Canada according to https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-recognised-documents.html, although in practice they probably would allow Canadians to return or transit on a journey to Canada.

Comment: That's an interesting list, because it lists "temporary passport", "emergency travel document for single journey only" and "single journey travel document" as separate things. There are also notes for some countries saying "accepted for return to Canada" and Sweden at least doesn't have that note. I think my last paragraph is the key - the consulate/embassy should know the details.